# pass dynamic id in jquery for select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to pass the id (generated dynamically in while loop ) to jquery.

```
echo '<div><td><select name=categoryname id="name-first'.$i.'" >';
echo '</select></td>';

$(function(){
   $('#name-first+<?php echo $i; ?>').on('change',function(){
       var selIndex= $("#name-second+<?php echo $i; ?> option:selected").index();
       $("#name-second+<?php echo $i; ?> option").eq(selIndex).prop('selected', true);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `+` in there which is not there when you generate the id:

```
$('#name-first+<?php echo $i; ?>').on('change',function(){
```

should be

```
$('#name-first<?php echo $i; ?>').on('change',function(){
```